# Use data from returning datatable?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I have a Datatable function like this

```
 public DataTable LoadCategory(SetupCategoryBO scBO)
        {
            DBConnect myConnection = new DBConnect();
            myConnection.connection.Open();

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ph.setup_category_proc", myConnection.connection);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            try
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitID", scBO.UnitID);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectID", scBO.ObjectID);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", scBO.UserID);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", scBO.Flag);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", scBO.ParID);

                comm.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                da.SelectCommand = comm;
                da.Fill(ds, "CategoryTable");
                return ds.Tables["CategoryTable"];
}
```

and I used this to try to get data from the datatable

```
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               dt = Scdal.LoadCategory(ScBo);
datagrid.Datacontext=dt;
```

Am i supposed to use a Sql data adapter?The datagrid shows up blank

AND the SetupCategoryBO is just used to initialize values.As far as i know The values are fine.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting data in the DataTable `dt`. ? Check that by debugging

Comment: Add break points in the `try` block and debug it to see if there is any error and doesn't throw in `catch` block. Or comment the `try` and `catch` block to see what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
DataTable dt = Scdal.LoadCategory(ScBo);
datagrid.Datacontext=dt.DefaultView;
```